# How to implement SSO using SAML 2.0 without using WIF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, asp.net-4.0, saml-2.0

## Behind the screen

1. We have two web application (website 1 and website 2 [SAML Service]) in different Domain.
2. We need to communicate for SSO purpose using SAML 2.0
3. WebSite 1 build a Sign SAML Assertion Request (using **.PFX certificate**) and POST to WebSite 2 (**SAML Service**) of a different Domain
4. Website 2 take this SAML request and asking for Credentials. Once validate, Website 2 redirect to Website 1 (Consume Page[AssertionConsumerServiceURL]) with SAML response.

**Question:**

1. Now within the **Website 1** (Consume Page[**AssertionConsumerServiceURL**]) what to do with **SAML response** in order to SSO ?
2. If a user want to **log-out** from WebSite 1, how to do that ? for *log-out* purpose any other SAML request need to be Post to website 2 ?
3. If a user *log-out* from Website 2 so what happen in Website 1 ?
4. Website 1 (**Issuer**) is a ASP.Net based application and Website 2 (**Destination Service Url**) is Java based application.

**Assumption**

1. AS per Google SSO is concern , when you log-on on to Google Account no need to separate login to ORKUT, GMAil. Google 1 this is example of SSO e.tc.

**Note:**

1. Website 1 is a Asp.Net Application.
2. Website 2 is Java based SAML service.

My main concern is that how to work with SAML response in ASP.NET application. I am not a expert of SAML 2.0 (SSO). So please guide me as a novice. I need your comments to clarify my knowledge and Code Snippet How to handle SAML response in SSO purpose withing Website 1 ?

Comment: [Ultimate SAML](http://www.componentpro.com/saml.net/) can help. Their [documentation](http://www.componentpro.com/doc/saml/) explains almost all your questions

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse, validate the signature. Use assertions to issue a local cookie to persist user session (you could use Forms authentication and forms cookie or issue SessionAuthenticationModule cookie)
2. Yes, you manually create a SAML request to sign out and post it to the identity provider.
3. The identity provider is supposed to "broadcast" the sign-out request to all authenticated applications. There are different implementations for this but from the Website1 point of view it means that a request will be made from the browser which tells the application to sign the user off. And technically the application just deletes its local cookie.
4. Doesn't really matter.